# Java App Memory Usage - Eclipse vs External Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-management

I run a Java application inside Eclipse and according to windows Task Manager, my memory is about 45000K. But when I export this application to a JAR file and run it via a batch, task manager says it's using 130000K memory. Anyone have any idea what would cause this? The application is on the same PC with the same inputs.

Comment: For starters, if you have a lot of printing, that could slow down the jar execution in the command line

Comment: I think the question was about memory. Do you run it as an external tool? Launched in a separate jvm?

Comment: @efekctive "java -jar MyApp.jar" is what I used to kick it off.

Comment: @yalpsideman - The same amount of prints is in the application whether it is run in eclipse or from a jar.

Comment: Different configurations. The task manager is also not the right place to examine memory usage by a java application.

Comment: check how eclipse launches it. It may make a difference

Comment: @Kayaman Suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: @efekctive Eclipse seems to call: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javaw.exe" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "long classpath here". Also it seems eclipse is using jdk1.8.0_60 while my command line is using 1.8.0_65

Comment: Check the -Xm args to see if there is a limit in the heap